# Why won't my paypal button center in my page

Tags: html, css

So I have a simple page:
www.kensandbox.info/centerthis

This is a simple html/css page and I'm trying to add a paypal button.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to center the button? I've tried adding the following:

```
<div align="center"> form code here </div>
```

No dice. I've even tried adding the center tag before the form.

The site code (simple html and css file) can be downloaded here:

www.kensandbox.info/centerthis/centerthis.zip

My guess is that one of the other CSS elements is overriding my change.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: `<div align="center">` is actually deprecated as of HTML 4.01. If the item has a set width, you can do `margin: 0 auto;`, or if it has a direct parent, you can give the parent the attribute `text-align: center`. But both `<div align="center">` and `<center>` are deprecated.

Comment: You're floating it left, therefore it wont be centred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at your code I would say the best way to center a div is usually make sure it's displayed as a block element (should be by default) and that its width is specified; then finally apply margin: auto.

e.g.

```
<div class="container">
    ...
    <div class="centered-element"> form code here </div>
    ...
</div>
```

where

```
container {
    width: 200px;
}
centered-element {
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block; /* to make sure it isn't being mucked up by your other css */
    float: none; /* to make sure it isn't being mucked up by your other css */
}
```

Edit:

I say to do it this way because, like I now see someone has commented, `<div align="center">` is deprecated and so is the `<center>` tag.  To expand, this is because your HTML should only be used to create the structure and semantics of your web page, and CSS should be used for the presentational aspects of it.  Keeping the two separate as best as you can will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Also it's best to design your CSS in a way where you shouldn't have to set `display: block;` on a div (because a div is already a block element) and your shouldn't have to unset a float by using `float: none;`.  For more on a good way to do that, improve your workflow, save yourself some time, and generally be awesome, check into object-oriented CSS a.k.a. ooCSS

Answer (score 3):

there is a `float:left` in `form input, form .btn` inside mycss.css

Add `float:none` to that input if you want to override.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and I want to thank the two individuals who took the time to answer.

The thing I didn't understand is how to look at a web page and see what CSS code was driving the formatting.

Some research lead me to a Chrome plug in named CSSViewer. Using this plugin and the information from the answer I was able to identify a float left css element that I simply had to change to a float center.

Thanks again for the help.